# Send data from controller to provider in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I trying to understand how providers work  in Angular 1.x.
I wrote this thing to test sending angular event object through provider:

```
var myMo = angular.module('myModule', [], function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%').endSymbol('%>');
});
myMo.provider ('eventTransport', function() {
  this.evento='';
  this.setEvent = function (event) {
    this.evento = event;
  };

  this.$get = function () {
    var enento = this.evento;
    return {
      returnName: function () {
        return evento;
      }
    };
  };
});
myMo.controller('MoCtrl', function ($scope, eventTransport) {
    $scope.signclick = function (eventobj) {
    console.warn('click');
    eventTransport.setEvent(eventobj);
    console.warn('clack');
    console.log(eventTransport.returnName());
    $scope.test = true;
}; });
```

And I got an error that `setEvent() is not a function`. Please tell me where is my mistake? Also show me how to send data into provider config function (myMo.config) I found a lot of examples to transfer data through angular service and no clear example of transporting data through provider.

Comment: Any why exactly do you want to define `setEvent` for the provider and not for the service then?

Comment: Because in angular developer guide i read: `You should use the Provider recipe only when you want to expose an API for application-wide configuration that must be made before the application starts. This is usually interesting only for reusable services whose behavior might need to vary slightly between applications.`
I need such configuration! :)

Comment: Sure, but the important point is "must be made before the application starts". If that's the case then doing it in the controller is too late and problematic (you'd need to do it in every topmost controller). If it's safe to do it in a controller then you can just as well define `setEvent` for the service itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service and it's provider are not the same. You can do some customon initialization to the `provider` at startup (you need to add the postfix **Provider**). But in the controller you will just get the object/function you defined in the `$get` function.

```
myMo.config(function (eventTransportProvider) {
  eventTransportProvider.setEvent(eventobj);
});
```

EDIT:
I think you don't need to do anything at startup time. You only need to use a provider to configurate your service. For your use-case you can just use simple getter and setter functions.

```
myMo.provider ('eventTransport', function() {

  this.$get = function () {
    var evento = '';
    return {
      getEvent: function () {
        return evento;
      },
      setEvent: function(event) {
        evento = event;
      }
    };
  };
});
```

a `provider` is just a more powerful version of a `factory` or a `service`, but most of the time you don't need to use a `provider`

```
myMo.factory('eventTransport', function() {
  var evento = '';

    return {
      getEvent: function () {
        return evento;
      },
      setEvent: function(event) {
        evento = event;
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: I get it with config, than you. But how i can send data in config from any other controller? Controller (data) -> Provider config (data) -> Provider (data)?

Comment: I know about factories, but i want to handle with provider. Ok. With your help I figured out how set\get data in provider - thank you. Now how i can set some internal data to providers config? Inserting some code like this:  `this.setConfName = function (inname) {
         name = inname;
 };` 
get me an Angular error.  How to insert data in config?

Comment: You use it the way as in your example, but you can't call this method from a controller. The `provider` functions are only meant to add some custom configuration at startup time - not to be used in the runtime

Answer (score 0):

Only those properties and functions defined within this.$get {} would be accessible from a controller. As it stands, I think your this.setEvent function would only be accessible during the config stage and you'd need to call it using something like:

```
myMo.config(['eventTransportProvider', function(eventTransportProvider) {
  eventTransportProvider.setEvent(...);
}]);
```

Do you need a provider? Perhaps a factory would be more suitable.

EDIT: If you need to be able to setEvent() from .config and from a controller, you could do something like this:

```
myMo.provider ('eventTransport', function eventTransportProvider() {
  var _evento = null;

  this.setEvent = function(event) {
    _evento = event;
  };

  this.$get = [function eventTransportFactory() {
    var service = {
      getEvent: function() {
        return _evento;
      },
      setEvent: function(event) {
        _evento = event;
      }
    };
    return service;
  }];
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how provider works. My goal is make provider that receive some config data, than provider take config data and made some changes with data that sending in provider from some controllers\directives.

Comment: Not very pretty - but thank you anyway! Any ideas how to insert external data in provider config?

Comment: By external data, do you mean from an ajax call?